# TypeError: this.setState is not a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to set property on reselection change.but this.setState() throws error .
Even I have binded onselectchange in constructor.

EDIT:when I tried to select all the rows from checkbox in column header it calls allSelectedRows() .here I'm getting count but its not setting

```
 rowSelection = {

    onChange: this.onSelectchange,
    onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => {
        console.log(selected, selectedRows, changeRows);
        this.allRowsSelected(selected, selectedRows, changeRows);
    },
};
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {           
        selectedRowKeys: []     
    }
    this.onSelectchange= this.onSelectchange.bind(this);        
}
allRowsSelected(selected, selectedRows, changeRows) {
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: selectedRows.length });
    console.log(this.state.selectedRowKeys.length);
}

onSelectchange(record){
    console.log(record);
    console.log(this.rowSelection);
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: record });

}
render(){
    return(
        <Table
            rowKey={data._id}
            columns={this.columns1}
            rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
            expandedRowRender={(record, index, indent, expanded) =>
            this.expanding(record, expanded)
            }

            onExpand={this.onExpand}
            dataSource={data} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please update your code as below one

```
rowSelection = {
    onChange: (record)=> this.onSelectchange(record),
};
```

I am not sure but I guess this will work for you!
Let me know if not working.